# Python openpyxl get date output format

Tags: python, openpyxl

i have an excel file that i cant change, where im getting some info with openpyxl, on this case i have a cell with this DATE format MM/DD/YYYY i need the output on python to be: %d/%m/%Y

Ive tried this :

```
ETD3 = sheet['F28'].value
ETD2 = str(ETD3)
ETD = datetime.strptime(ETD2,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

I get this error :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\eclipse-workspace\TEst\RunFaster.py", line 102, in <module>
    ETD = datetime.strptime(ETD2,'%d/%m/%Y')
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2021-10-15 00:00:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

How can i make this work correctly? (im new in python and also on programming)

Comment: There's no need to do this: Openpyxl converts dates and times for you.

Comment: @charlie-clark Well yes, you right, but my question was about the output format that i needed, i was able  to solve with this: `ETD = datetime.strftime(ETD2,'%d/%m/%Y')`  otherwise i would get %Y/%m/%d

Comment: That is all you need to do because it is a datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.strptime` grabs a string and converts it into a datetime object. The format you give it tells it how to interpret the string it's grabbing. In this case, you're telling it that you're giving it a string formatted like `'%d/%m/%Y'`, when in fact it appears you're giving it a string formatted like `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. This is the format string you should give it. You will then have a datetime object representing that date/time. If you want to have a new string in the format you indicated, take that datetime object and use the `.strftime` method, passing your format string to it, and it will output the string how you want it:

```
ETD3 = sheet['F28'].value
ETD2 = str(ETD3)
DT = datetime.strptime(ETD2,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ETD = DT.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation i could make it work not converting to string and using  .strftime

`ETD2 = sheet['F28'].value
#ETD2 = str(ETD3)
ETD = datetime.strftime(ETD2,'%d/%m/%Y')`

output:
`15/10/2021`

Answer (score 0):

This is iso you can apply:

```
from datetime import datetime

ETD = datetime.fromisoformat('2021-10-15 00:00:00'))
print(f"{ETD.day}/{ETD.month}/{ETD.year}")
```

Output:

```
15/10/2021
```